# Отправка вложений в письме PHP

Tags: php, email

Пишу скрипт отправки почты с вложением.

```
$file = "act.pdf"; // файл
$mailTo = "rumyancevaa@afanasy.ru"; // кому
$from = "rumyancevaa@afanasy.ru"; // от кого
$subject = "Общественная приемная"; // тема письма
$message = "Контактный телефон обратившегося "; // текст письма
$r = sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message, $file); // отправка письма c вложением
echo ($r)?'<center><h2 class="action_title">Ваша заявка отправлена! Скоро мы ее рассмотрим и позвоним вам!<h2></center>':'Ошибка. Письмо не отправлено!';
//$r = sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message); // отправка письма без вложения
//echo ($r)?'Письмо отправлено':'Ошибка. Письмо не отправлено!';


function sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $message, $file = false){
    $separator = "---"; // разделитель в письме
    // Заголовки для письма
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n"; // задаем от кого письмо
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$separator\""; // в заголовке указываем разделитель
    // если письмо с вложением
    if($file){
        $bodyMail = "--$separator\n"; // начало тела письма, выводим разделитель
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n"; // кодировка письма
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n"; // задаем конвертацию письма
        $bodyMail .= $message."\n"; // добавляем текст письма
        $bodyMail .= "--$separator\n";
       $fileRead = fopen($file, "r"); // открываем файл
        $contentFile = fread($fileRead, filesize($file)); // считываем его до конца
        fclose($fileRead); // закрываем файл
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n"; 
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; // кодировка файла
        $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n";
        $bodyMail .= chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFile))."\n"; // кодируем и прикрепляем файл
        $bodyMail .= "--".$separator ."--\n";
    // письмо без вложения
    }else{
        $bodyMail = $message;
    }
    $result = mail($mailTo, $subject, $bodyMail, $headers); // отправка письма
    return $result;
}
```

Каким образом можно добавить второе вложение из input type = "file" на форме?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Три простых шага для решения данной проблемы:

1. Посмотреть на календарь и уточнить, какой сейчас век на дворе.
2. Аккуратно выделить этот код, и нажать клавишу Del
3. Скачать [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
4. Забыть все эти кустарные ковыряния как страшный сон.

В итоге код должен получиться примерно таким:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer file sender';
$mail->msgHTML("My message body");
    // Attach uploaded files
$mail->addAttachment($filename1);
$mail->addAttachment($filename2);
$r = $mail->send();
```

следует понимать, что отправка почты - это не просто копирование в свой скрипт каких-то определенных сочетаний символов, к оторые случайно сработали в прошлом веке у автора какой-либо допотопной статьи. Это гораздо более сложный процесс, который включает множество нюансов. И поэтому отправку почты надо не лепить вручную из подручных средств на ходу, а доверить проверенному и отлаженному решению.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Так и правда намного легче и быстрее. Все, что нужно было реализовал!

Comment: Всё бы ничего, только для PhpMailer желательны права root, Composer и VDS, на обычном хостинге такого не предоставляют...
или я не прав?

Comment: @Андрей PhpMailer и Composer - это скрипты, написанные на языке похапе, и если на обычном хостинге предоставляют возможность запускать скрипты на похапе, то получится запустить и PhpMailer.

Answer (score 6):

В функцию бросайте массив $_FILES и далее его разбираете:

```
function sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $From, $subject_text, $message, $_FILES){

        $to = $mailTo;

        $EOL = "\r\n"; // ограничитель строк, некоторые почтовые сервера требуют \n - подобрать опытным путём
        $boundary     = "--".md5(uniqid(time()));  // любая строка, которой не будет ниже в потоке данных. 

        $subject= '=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject_text) . '?=';

        $headers    = "MIME-Version: 1.0;$EOL";   
        $headers   .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"$EOL";  
        $headers   .= "From: $From\nReply-To: $From\n";  

        $multipart  = "--$boundary$EOL";   
        $multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8$EOL";   
        $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$EOL";   
        $multipart .= $EOL; // раздел между заголовками и телом html-части 
        $multipart .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));   

        #начало вставки файлов

        foreach($_FILES["file"]["name"] as $key => $value){
            $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $file = fopen($filename, "rb");
            $data = fread($file,  filesize( $filename ) );
            fclose($file);
            $NameFile = $_FILES["file"]["name"][$key]; // в этой переменной надо сформировать имя файла (без всякого пути);
            $File = $data;
            $multipart .=  "$EOL--$boundary$EOL";   
            $multipart .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$NameFile\"$EOL";   
            $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64$EOL";   
            $multipart .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$NameFile\"$EOL";   
            $multipart .= $EOL; // раздел между заголовками и телом прикрепленного файла 
            $multipart .= chunk_split(base64_encode($File));   

        }

        #>>конец вставки файлов

        $multipart .= "$EOL--$boundary--$EOL";

        if(!mail($to, $subject, $multipart, $headers)){
            echo 'Письмо не отправлено';
        } //Отправляем письмо
        else{
            echo 'Письмо отправлено';
        }

    }
```

P.S.: код проверен на работоспособность.

Answer (score 0):

$_FILES - глобальный массив, доступен везде, передавать в функцию не обязательно. Способ с PhpMailer - лучшее решение.