# Отправка писем с аттачем

Tags: php

Добрый день. Есть форма отправки.

```
<label><input type="text" name="message" value="" title="{'soobshenie'|translate}" placeholder="{'soobshenie'|translate}" /></label>
<label><input type="file" name="attachfile" maxlength="64"></label>
```

И обработчик такого вида

`$body .= "Сообщение: ".trim($_POST["data"]["message"])."<br />";`

Как прикрепить аттач к данному письму?

Comment: Можете толко отправлять линк файла!

Comment: в смысле только линк?

Comment: Неправильный ответ. Прикреплять аттачи можно. Уже были ответы на подобные вопросы на со, да вот первый же: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456465/

Comment: Таких вопросов много уже было, [поищите на со](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE).