# Отправка файла/фотографии через форму

Tags: php

Суть идеи такова. Допустим есть форма на сайте, туда загружаем файл и нажимаем условный "отправить" и файл уходит на почту,на подобии как в пхп mailto,как можно это реализовать?

Comment: уже был такой вопросик, сейчас найду.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456465/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5-php