# Как в форму обратной связи добавить вложение файла?

Tags: php, ajax, form, форма, отправка

Не пойму как отправлять вложенные файлы в форме. Код

```html
<form id="feedback-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">

  <div id="feedback-return" class="alert" style="display: none"></div>

  <div>
    <label>Ф.И.О.</label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Почта</label>
    <input type="email" name="email">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Телефон</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Файл</label>
    <input type="file" name="file">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Предложения и пожелания</label>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div>
    <input id="feedback-submit" type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </div>

</form>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  "use strict";

  $('#feedback-submit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
      message = $('#feedback-return'),
      form = $('#feedback-form');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '../contact/feedback-process.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: $('#feedback-form').serialize(),
      success: function(data) {

        if (data.info !== 'error') {
          $this.parents('form').find('input[type=text],input[type=email],input[type=hidden],input[type=file],textarea,select').filter(':visible').val('');
          message.hide().removeClass('alert-success').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-success').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
        } else {
          message.hide().removeClass('alert-success').removeClass('alert-danger').addClass('alert-danger').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
        }
      }
    });
  });

});
```

Код обработчика PHP (feedback-process.php)

```
if($_POST) {

    $to = '--почта--';
    $subject = '--тема--';

    $name        = $_POST['name'];
    $mail        = $_POST['email'];
    $message     = $_POST['message'];
    $tel         = $_POST['phone'];

}

$message = '
Имя: '.$name.'<br>
Почта:  '.$mail.'<br>
Телефон: '.$tel.'<br>
Сообщение: '.$message.'<br>
';

$check_tel = '/(8|7|\+7)?9\d{9}/';



if ($name == '') {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "<b>Ошибка!</b> Не указано имя."));
    exit();
} else if ($mail == '') {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "<b>Ошибка!</b> Не указана почта"));
    exit();
} else if ($tel == '') {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "<b>Ошибка!</b> Не указан телефон."));
    exit();
} else if (!preg_match($check_tel, $tel)) {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Не верно указан <b>телефон</b>! <br>Номер должен быть в формате <b>+7×××××××××</b> или <b>8×××××××××</b>"));
    exit();
} else {

    //Send Mail
    $headers =
    'From: --почта--'. "\r\n".
    'Reply-To: --почта--'. "\r\n".
    'MIME-Version: 1.0'. "\r\n".
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'. "\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/'.phpversion();

    if (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => "<b>Спасибо!</b> Ваше сообщение отправлено."));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "<b>Ошибка!</b> Сообщение не отправлено, попробуйте еще раз."));
    }
}
```

Как обрабатывать поле файла? Всё что нагуглил присылает письмо без вложений.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Нужно учесть что ваши данные отправляются в JSON формате в форму PHP, включить отладчик и посмотреть что происходит в PHP - какие значения где находятся и т.д. А уже после этого можно посмотреть как использовать сущ. код для своих нужд (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/456465/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B5-php)

Comment: Файлы так через ajax __не передаются__. Требуется `js FormData`